# excel: building timelines

Tags: vba, excel, timeline

does anyone know if there is an easy way to create timelines in excel? for example, i would enter data and information and that information would be built into a timeline graph? i am looking for a vba or other solution?

Comment: You need to tell us more. Timeline charts are the default. Information and data are the same thing to Excel. What would you like the result to look like? Can you provide examples of the input?

Comment: please do not upvote this unless you have an answer. im not here for points.

Comment: @JOE You misunderstand what voting is for. I upvoted your question not because I want to do you a favor, but because a good answer to this question will help ME. And I'm signaling that to prospect answerers.

Comment: @BELI gotcha! please dont upvote it

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a chart with time on x-axis and some other value on y-axis, like for example plotting sales against time? If so then a straightforward XY plot of your data will do this. If this isn't what you are after it might help if you clarified what you want.

Comment: @rich a simple version of this http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/examples/test_example/test.html

Answer (score 1):

Does this example help?

http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/create-a-timeline.html

Comment: @JOE: In what way does that example not help? You're not giving Richard much to work with here.

Comment: @michael: if i ask you where can i get an apple and you tell me that olives are your favorite food, how should i describe why your response is not helpful?

Comment: @JOE - I don't know if it's how you mean to come across or just a lost in translation thing, but you kind of seem like you're snapping at people a bit... We're only trying to work out what you want so we can maybe help. For my part, I'm still none the wiser as to what you're actually after, and don't have infinite free time, so I'm going to move on from this one now, all the best in finding a solution though.